# Import and analyze multiple CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am a bit in trouble analyzing several CSV files in Python 3.7.
I have these files in a folder, and I specify its path through "filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)".

At this point I started a for loop to analyze the files needed in a loop, that is the goal of the script.
What I can see, is that the script takes indeed all the N files but it performed operations only on the last one. Also, I don't want to concatenate into DF with Pandas all the files: the code works well on each file, I wanted just to make the execution faster to make it run just once instead ten times or so.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from pylinac.core.profile import SingleProfile
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'auto')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.lift()
root.focus_force()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost',True)
root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',True)
root.withdraw()

read_files = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)

#csv selection

for files in read_files:
    print(files)
    ascii_files = os.path.basename(files)
    split_filenames = ascii_files.split(".", 1)
    field = split_filenames[0]
    with open(files, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            list_import = list(reader)

#here start CSV postprocessing ...
#delete the first two rows of cvs file

    del list_import[0]
    del list_import[0]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_import)
first_column=df.columns[0]
df=df.drop([first_column], axis=1)
unif_map=df.to_numpy(dtype=float) 
# analysis continue...
```

It is processing all the files because when I ask to print them with print(files), it prints out all the csv filenames in the folder:

```
C:/trial/depth 23 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 24 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 25 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 26 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 27 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 28 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 29 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 30 distal.csv
C:/trial/depth 31 distal.csv
```

But I guess it analyzes only the last one, indeed it displays only figures relative to the last file (C:/trial/depth 31 distal.csv) and when I ask to print the name of the CSV analyzed I got "depth 31 distal", indeed I had no output for the other files.

Comment: Append your cvs files into a list (or directly a dataframe) then convert to dataframes.

Comment: Hi, it's already in the code (df = pd.DataFrame(list_import)). What I think is that the "for loop" is not complete or something is wrong there, also because the code runs well (I have no error). Perhaps the issue is in the line " ascii_files = os.path.basename(files)", because "ascii_file = depth 31 distal.csv". Also, I want a loop because I can run a not fixed number of CSV (or at least this was in my mind)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to place everything into the loop. What happens here is that you go through all the files, and the loop only keeps the **latest** record for your *list_import* that goes into the dataframe creation.

Comment: Yes, I understood the point, but in practice I don't how to implement it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Create an empty df before the loop df_all=pd.DataFrame(), then move df=... under the hood of the loop and in end of the loop place df_all = df_all.append(df)